# Unable to perform actions in IE11 with selenium in c#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, kendo-ui

Can anyone help me in fixing the issue related to internet explorer. I am not able to perform any kind of actions  such as dragging and dropping the web elements using IE driver but these actions perfectly works in chrome and firefox. I tried configuring the internet explorer options as shown below:

```
 InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions {EnableNativeEvents = false};

 WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IDEServerPath"], options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

Any help in this is appreciated and also please let me know if you need any other inputs.

I found that these our front end project uses kendo UI. I think this is something to do with IE and kendoUI any reference to solve the problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions
           {
              EnableNativeEvents = true,
              RequireWindowFocus = true
           };

WebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IDEServerPath"], options,
              TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
```

setting the above options actually fix my problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to download [IEDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and give it's path to the contractor

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver("c:\driver", options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

Comment: I downloaded the IEDriver and I am giving the path using ```ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IDEServerPath"]```.I think that is not the issue.